# How does matplotlib's radial axis scaling work by default?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some points using matplotlib with a polar projection. My impression was that the axes should automatically scale to fit the data, but that doesn't seem to be happening consistently.

In this example, the behavior seems inconsistent:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_polar(coords_rads):
    fig = plt.figure()
    #ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1.2, 1.2], polar=True)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
    magnitudes, angles = [list(i) for i in zip(*coords_rads)]
    print angles, magnitudes
    plt.scatter(angles, magnitudes)


coords_rads = [(10, 0.0), (200, 1.5707963267948966), (30, -1.5707963267948966), (100, 5.497787143782138)]
plot_polar(coords_rads)  # works (radius is scaled to just over 200):
coords_rads = [(3.391, 2.061670178918302), (169.116, 0.0), (106.869, 1.0799224746714915)]
plot_polar(coords_rads)  # doesn't work (radius is scaled to 100)
```

output:

Plot 1 - works as expected (radius is scaled to just over 200):
[image: Plot 1 - working]

Plot 2 - not working as expected (radius is scaled to 100):
[image: Plot 2 - not working]

Edit:

Here's an IPython Notebook demonstrating the issue: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/gabrielgrant/b6bd4ad38355a06126f5

Comment: My first inclination is that it's something weird due to mixing the `pyplot` and object-oriented interfaces.  Does it still do that when you replace `plt.scatter` with `ax.scatter`?

Comment: What you're describing would be a bug.  However, I can't reproduce your problem. (The r-axis is scaled 0-250 in the second example.) What version of matplotlib are you using?  (On a side note, the autoscaling of 0-250 for the second plot seems odd, as well.)

Comment: @Ajean changing `plt.scatter` to `ax.scatter` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: @JoeKington I'm using matplotlib version 1.4.0, which I believe is the latest

Comment: The second scales to 250 for me as well, using 1.3.1. Curious...

Comment: I added a link to an IPython Notebook for testing. Would one of you mind testing with 1.4.0 to see whether it's just an issue for me?

Comment: I can't run what you posted there, it's just a viewer...

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour on 1.4.0.  Can you please make an issue on github for this?